# Fetching contents of a file that was sent through cURL POST

Tags: php, file, post, curl

So after researching a bit, I found out that it is possible to send a file through cURL to another page. Here is the code that is doing the sending part:

```
$url = 'http://someabc.com/api.php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$postData = array(
    'array' => "@".realpath('array.txt'),
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

### Receiving Part (api.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['array']))
{
    $string = $_POST['array'];
    echo $string;
}
else
{
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

When I run the page containing the cURL request, I'm getting `Not found` printed on the page.

Does this mean I'm capturing the data in a wrong way? If so, what would be the way to get the contents of `array.txt` from `api.php` page?

### UPDATE

After using `$_FILES` as suggested by Jon, I received the following array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => array.txt
    [type] => application/octet-stream
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpPQZXf9
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 77413
)
```

Now I tried getting the contents of this file using:

```
$tmp = $_FILES['array'];
$string = file_get_contents($tmp['name']['tmp_name']);
```

but got the error `Warning: file_get_contents(a) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory` which would mean I'm not referencing the file correctly. Where did I go wrong now?

Comment: anything in `$_FILES` array?  Because you're trying to send a file, so that's where the data should be rather than in `$_POST`.

Comment: But I'm not using `<input type="file" />`...simply picking up a text file from the directory and sending it.

Comment: You're sending a file - it's the same thing on the receiving end.

Comment: Ok. I did get something. Updating answer.

Comment: You can't access the file from the `tmp` directy, for that, you'd have to [`move_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) (At least, normally you shouldn't be able to.)

Comment: It should be $string = file_get_contents($tmp['tmp_name']);

Comment: @Jon If you could post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as the answer. It's working now.

Comment: Sure thing.  Will be a few while I make it look nice and all ^^

Comment: No problem. Anyhow the system won't let me accept an answer for at least 10 mins or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part before the update, the problem exists because when posting a file to a page, regardless of the method in which it happens (ie `<input type='file />`, `curl`, etc) it is always available to PHP via the [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) variable, which is an associative array, in your case, should be `$_FILES['array']` containing the information of the temporary file location. The array should be similar to:

```
Array 
(
    [array] => Array
    (
            [name] => array.txt
            [type] => encoding type
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/path/file
            [error] => 0 (if no error)
            [size] => [filesize]
    )
)
```

From there, to access the file, you'd want to move it from the `tmp` directory to one you have permission to access. This is accomplished with [`move_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).  An example of usage with this would be:

```
$upDir = 'uploads/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['array']['tmp_name'], $upDir. $_FILES['array']['name']);
```

From there, the file will be on the server under the relative path to the php file in `uploads/array.txt`, and you can do what you will with it there. ^^

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to post a file the data will be available on $_FILES. you can check using the following code

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

if you get your file information from $_FILES then you can replace your check "if(isset($_POST['array']))" with

```
if(count($_FILES))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

to access files content try:

```
$tmp = $_FILES['array'];
$string = file_get_contents($tmp['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: Yes, I've crossed that roadblock. Now I'm trying to retrieve the contents of that file on the receiving end.

Comment: Thanks Zubair. That helped. Unfortunately, I can only choose 1 answer and since Jon had directed me in the right direction first, I'd have to go with him.